# Macro to merge two tables in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I’ve had this problem several times and never found a satisfactory way of solving it. I’m sure it must be an easy macro to get this done.
I got a big table with names in the row, months in the columns, and values. Like this example:

```
      Jan-17  Feb-17  Mar-17
CS      12     10      9
GS       1      5      3
JPM     43     35     40
UBS     11     15     13
```

And every month I get the new values but the issue is: the names are not necessarily the same. There are a few new names and a few old that don’t appear anymore. Let say this as an example:

```
     Apr-17
BNP    21
Citi   75
CS     11
UBS     8
```

I need to add this to the original big table. So, I need to add a new row full of zeroes for the new stuff of this month and put a zero in this month for the old stuff that disappear. I want something like this as a result:

```
     Jan-17  Feb-17  Mar-17  Apr-17
BNP     0      0       0      21
Citi    0      0       0      75
CS     12     10       9      11
GS      1      5       3       0
JPM    43     35      40       0
UBS    11     15      13       8
```

The best solution I got until now is loop thought the names in both tables and compare them. When It found a mismatch check the next name in the main table, if those two match that means is a new name. if not, I check the next name in the new table and if that match it means that’s an old name that has stopped appearing. See my code below:

```
Sub FixColumnsNames()

'This sub Compare the names in the Summary and the Input tab and put the same names on both
Dim LoopRow As Integer
LoopRow = 1

While Sheets("Input").Range("A" & LoopRow) <> "Grand Total"
'Walkthought tha name list until we find the end (Grand Total)

    If Sheets("Input").Range("A" & LoopRow).Value <> Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & LoopRow).Value Then
    'If two names don't match lets analyse:

        If Sheets("Input").Range("A" & LoopRow + 1).Value = Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & LoopRow).Value Then
        'New Strategy
            Sheets("Summary").Rows(LoopRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & LoopRow).Value = Sheets("Input").Range("A" & LoopRow).Value
        End If

        If Sheets("Input").Range("A" & LoopRow).Value = Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & LoopRow + 1).Value Then
        'Old strategy (it has stopped apearing)
            Sheets("Input").Rows(LoopRow).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Sheets("Input").Range("A" & LoopRow).Value = Sheets("Summary").Range("A" & LoopRow).Value
        End If

    End If
    LoopRow = LoopRow + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

This assumes the names are always shorted alphabetically, but this is not a problem for me. This is not a great solution because it fails when there are two old or new names consecutives (among other things).

Can someone please advise how to solve this? Some code or pseudo code would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you need VBA? I'm pretty sure you could use `Index/Match` or `VLOOKUP` formulas instead...

Comment: I don't have to use VBA, but I'm looking for a way of doing this quick and easy. The real thing have a few hundreds rows and this process need to be done a few times on similar tables That's why it's better if it's more an automated solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this much faster with a Vlookup formula. First, find new April values. you can do that with Vlookup April values vs Table values.

[image]

Now `copy/PasteValue` values that are not found (ones with #N/A Vlookup value) below your main table,and use this formula in cell `E2`(adjust range to your needs)  `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,$H$1:$I$10,2,FALSE),0)`. Drag formula to bottom.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You duplicated CS and UBS instead of adding the new ones but I get your idea. I'll think about getting the vlookup mechanic into a macro.

Comment: You are right, I corrected my answer. could you please mark as answered?